# Add child to existing route from another module in zend framework 2

Tags: module, zend-framework2, routes

I have a module with following route :

```
'route'    => '/user-management[/:action][/:id][/[page/:page]][/[search-by/:search-by]][/[search-text/:search-text]]',
```

I want to add ban functionnality in another module and If I locate /user/management/ban/id it locates BanModule\BanController\BanAction. How to set configuration in ban module without dependacy to user management module ?
( A solution is adding complete user management route to ban module but it overwrites user management module route and it doesn't take effect when we change user management route )

Comment: This is exactly the reason why generic routes are not good. Optional parameters should not be defined within the route but they should be query parameters. And then you'd be best advised to write specific routes and use `child_routes` to define new children routes.

Comment: @Sam You mean add a child route for every action ?

Comment: Yep, that's faster and makes stuff like you want much easier.

Comment: I would use http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-part